# How to split html to full-screen height pages?

Tags: javascript, html, pagination, margins

I need to split some html content to pages, so that each page would have height of the screen and some predefined width. Page split can happen in the middle of paragraph (or probably some other html element), so this situation should be handled somehow.

What I really want to achieve is the effect of reading the book, page by page. I assume there will be a need for some javascript, so I'd prefer to to this with jQuery, but if other framework is required, it's also okay.

I have to admit that I'm quite new to HTML and all, so sorry if my guess is stupid, but currently I'm considering the following approach: measure actual height of the visible area (need to figure out how yet), then take my html document and incrementally take tag after tag, put this into invisible div and calculate its resulting height. When I'll have its height more than page height, I'm done. However, this approach will not work in case of long tags, e.g. long paragraph.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: thanks for your previous answers. I tried to use approach of manual calculating the size of the elements, and encountered one problem which I cannot solve in a good way. This is problem of collapsing margins. What I'm trying to do is to loop through all the paragraphs in my document and sum up results of .outerHeight(true) jQuery call. This should give me the full height of element, including padding, margin and border. And it actually does what it says, but the problem here is that it doesn't take collapsing margins into account. Because of that I end up with wrong overall size (bigger than real one), because browser throws away some of margins (of adjacent paragraphs in my case), but I take them into account.

Any ideas how to solve this other than introducing the algorithm deciding which margins are collapsed and which are not? I think it is ugly...

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS3 multi-column rules, example: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html
Or for support in all browsers use a javascript plugin: http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

This plugin even has a multi-page multi-column example: http://welcome.totheinter.net/2009/06/18/dynamic-multi-page-multi-column-newsletter-layout-with-columnizer/

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one framework which seems to do what you need (and a bit more): https://github.com/Treesaver/treesaver

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will give you the height (in pixels) of an element with the height() function.

`jQuery("BODY").height()` will give you the maximum height of the view port (though only if your content height is >= the height of the BODY - otherwise it will give you the height of how much space the body is taking up in the view port.)

Counting the heights of the P tags (or other tags) seems like a good way to go. I suppose if you want to break up the content of a P tag for large paragraphs, you could define a maximum "breakage" height for the last P tag on a page. You can then break rest of the contents of the P tag by creating a new P tag with `jQuery("#the-next-page-id).append(jQuery("<P>"+restOfTheParagraphContent+"</P>"))`

Comment: It would seem that something like this CSS multi-column layout [link]http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/ would be helpful except in this case you would want multi-row layout where each row counts as a page. I think I remember a jQuery plugin that did something like that.

Comment: Any word on this? I am curious. Is css-multicol helpful? Is jQuery an option?

Answer (score 0):

Use your own logic to calculate the *height* of each element in the html body
using jQuery code

```
$('selector').height();
```

Using this, you can calculate the height of some html elements and decide how much 
elements should be displayed on your device screen.

for more, please visit [jQuery Height Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still looking for something like this I recently did it using JQuery. It also leaves the first page empty (for title and such):

https://jsfiddle.net/xs31xzvt/

It basically iterates over the movable items and insert them into a new div if the previous div is full.

```
 (function($) {

    $(document).ready(formatPages)
    function formatPages() {
        var container = $('.container');
        var subPage = $('.subpage').get(0);
        var subPageHeight = subPage.offsetHeight;
        var subPageScrollHeight = subPage.scrollHeight;
        // See how many pages we'll need
        var pages = Math.floor(subPageScrollHeight / subPageHeight) + 1;
        //add a new page
        var pageCount = 2;
        var pageDiv = createPageDiv(pageCount);
        var subPageDiv = createSubPageDiv(pageCount);

        var addPage = function (){
            pageCount++;
            pageDiv = createPageDiv(pageCount);
            subPageDiv = createSubPageDiv(pageCount);
            pageDiv.append(subPageDiv);
            container.append(pageDiv);
            pageContentHeight = 0;
        }
        addPage()
        container.append(pageDiv);
        $('.movable').each(function() {
            var element = $(this);
            //remove the element
            element.detach();
            //try to add the element to the current page
            if (pageContentHeight + element.get(0).offsetHeight > subPageHeight) {
                subPageDiv.append(getFooterDiv().show());
                //add a new page
                addPage();
            }
            subPageDiv.append(element);
            pageContentHeight += element.get(0).offsetHeight;
        });
    }



    function createPageDiv(pageNum) {
        return $('<div/>', {
            class: 'page',
            id: 'page' + pageNum
        });
    }
    function createSubPageDiv(pageNum) {
        return $('<div/>', {
            class: 'subpage',
            id: 'subpage' + pageNum
        });
    }
    function getFooterDiv() {
        return $('.footer').first().clone();
    }
}(jQuery));
```